# VS code displays listing directory instead of serving the html file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, web-development-server

I wanted to serve the Disp.html file through nodejs following the code I learned through a Youtube tutorial.

```js
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const fileContent = fs.readFileSync("Disp.html");

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { "Content-type": "text/html" });
  res.end(fileContent);
});

server.listen(80, "127.0.0.1", () => {
  console.log("Listening on port 80");
});
```

I have created a folder in VS Code with this app.js and Disp.html as the files. Every time I run the code it displays the listing directory in place of the HTML content that I am expecting to view.

What can I do to get the expected result?

Comment: Something is very wrong with how you are running it. It *sounds* like you might be running the VS Code live server and accessing that instead of running the server you're written in the above code.

Comment: Seems like you got this file outside the www directory, start the node app and have the correct files in the public directory, or what ever name it's for you.

Comment: Note that dealing with `http.createServer` directly is almost always far more annoying than your time is worth and that you're usually better off using Express.js.

Comment: @PatricNox — No. There's no `www` directory because this isn't Apache/IIS/whatever. If the `Disp.html` was in the wrong place then it would error trying to read it.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, I got it. The local host was at port 5500 not 80, changing that in the code got me the html file served.

So it was server.listen(5500, ...)